# How to use object attributes in belongs_to :select association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have CartItem model that has a belongs_to relation with Product

```
def CartItem
  belongs_to :product, :select => "*, get_product_price_for_shop(#{self.shop_id}) as shop_price"
end
```

As you can see above I have postgresql function that calculates price for specific shop and I want to use it in select clause of products so I can refer to it like this:

```
@cart_item.product.shop_price
```

I'm looking for a way to pass `shop_id` attribute from `CartItem` to belongs_to `:select` key.

Answer (score 0):

A quick thought : did you try a proc ?

```
def CartItem
  belongs_to :product, :select => proc { "*, get_product_price_for_shop(#{self.shop_id}) as shop_price" }
end
```

Comment: it didn't work - I'm getting an error `TypeError: Cannot visit Proc`